# Create JS array from input field values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have x number of input fields with class='agency_field'. How can I create a JS array that contain the values of all fields with this class?

Using jQuery, this gives a syntax error:

> $(".agency_field").each(function(index)
>   {         agencies[] = $(this).val();     });

Comment: Holy @#%# - you just got 6 answers within a minute of each other.

Comment: Hard to beat SO response times!

Comment: LOL Five each() answers, and only one map() answer...

Comment: @Šime - I'm not sure how well-known map() is. each() is seen all over the place and it's easy to use (more familiarity). I gave this karim's answer +1 though because the documentation says map() is especially useful for this scenario.

Comment: That being said, where's the love for the each() answers? They're still acceptable answers, and more readable IMHO.

Comment: @McStretch The each() answers are suboptimal. map() is the way to go. I don't think that suboptimal solutions should get up-votes.

Comment: @Šime - Suboptimal how? Is the runtime measurably faster for map?

Comment: @McStretch Btw simple code is usually easier to read, and sophisticated, optimized code is generally hard to read (for a beginner). But that doesn't mean that beginners should avoid it. They should try to understand it, and then it will become more readable.

Comment: @Šime - I agree, but how is this optimized? I saw your comment below that map() has the potential to run slower (although in general it doesn't), so you're trading simplicity and possibly runtime performance for a sophisticated solution. Don't get me wrong, I like the solution, but I don't think it's more readable to anyone. I feel like it's too easy to forget the "get()" at the end as well, which could potentially add more time to debugging.

Comment: @McStretch The runtime difference is measured in microseconds on my machine, so practically there is no runtime difference. The each() solution is suboptimal because you have to declare an array variable, and then manually populate it in each iteration. The `map().get()` chain creates the array for you, without you having to declare a dedicated array variable. This is more flexible = better.

Comment: @Šime - You do have to declare an array variable, you just don't have to initialize it. In my opinion this increases readability, because anyone modifying the code immediately recognizes what is going on. Simplicity = better (if performance doesn't matter) :P  And again I wouldn't expect that I have to call `.get()` after using map(). I would expect map() to return an array for me.

Comment: @McStretch Well, I'm a big fan of complex, sophisticated, optimized code. Obviously, beginners will have a hard time reading such code. But I'm certainly not going to change my code to suit them. Sophisticated code is better than naive code.

Comment: @Šime - naive and simple are not one in the same. Are you being sarcastic about being a fan of complex code? I agree that you shouldn't have to code to the lowest common denominator, but in this case I hardly think using each() instead of map() is doing this.

Comment: @McStretch Complex as in hard to understand for beginners. It's probably not the best word choice. I'm not a native speaker, so that happens to me occasionally. For this particular problem, map() is the more sophisticated solution, which makes each() the more naive solution. The purpose of map() is to transform a collection of DOM elements into a collection of values related to those elements, which is exactly what this problem requires. Also, map() is more flexible because it **does not** require you to declare a dedicated variable, because...

Comment: @McStretch ... You can use the array value returned by `$(...).map(...).get()` by itself. For instance you can return it, or even pass it as an argument into another function. This flexibility cannot be achieved if you go with the each() solution.

Comment: @McStretch Yes, naive and simple are not the same. I would say that both solutions are equally simple (based on code-size). However, I would also say that the each() solution is more naive.

Comment: @Šime - My main point is that each() is not a naive solution, because the code you use with each is self-documenting. map() isn't even a good name for what's going on (maybe collect would be better?). So you have this poorly named method which collects a value, and then you have to call get() on it at the end, which is an odd extra step. Maybe the reason you didn't see more answers for map() is because it's poorly named and/or misunderstood. I don't think we're changing each other's minds, but I do think it's a cool solution - just not always the best.

Comment: @McStretch I wouldn't know if map is poorly named, because I don't know the meaning of that word in programming parlance. Afaik, Mozilla introduced the "map" Array method in JavaScript 1.5 back in 2000. jQuery is just using that name to achieve analogue functionality on jQuery objects. But even if it is poorly named, that's irrelevant. It's the functionality of the method that counts, not its name. Also, calling get() at the end is not an odd extra step. It's perfectly reasonable - it transforms the jQuery object into a regular array.

Comment: @McStretch I have the feeling that you're using ignorance as an argument against map() and get(). The postulate is obviously that the programmer does have full understanding of the jQuery API. In that case, map() is the better solution because its mere purpose is to address this kind of issue. @karim already mentioned this a comment to his answer. *"The .map() method is particularly useful for getting or setting the value of a collection of elements."*

Comment: @Šime - I'd say you're partially right there. I said up above that I wonder if there's so much ignorance concerning the existence of the method because some team member decides that it isn't any more useful than using .each, and thus other team members might not get the chance to see the method. Maybe it's the naming of the method, as I suggested earlier. When I'm perusing the api, the word `map` makes it seem like I would use it for a key/value pair (map this value to that key), not `collect` things in an array (the word I would have used).

Comment: @McStretch Yes, thats true. Many jQuery programmers only understand a fraction of the jQuery API. I don't work in a team (you probably can tell `:)`), but my solution would be to teach them. If someone doesn't understand the language or the API, then he should invest in it and learn it properly. I'm not willing to degrade my code one bit for them. The code is more important than the programmers. The programmers should adapt to the code, not the other way around.

Comment: @Šime - I agree that developers should be taught new ways to do things. I disagree that each() is a degradation though :). Btw I don't work with jQuery full time, and I do stuff on my own right now. I guess I need to straight up peruse the whole API to better affiliate myself with all of the methods. Anyways, good talk, we'll have to do this again sometime :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map) instead, which is perhaps more suited to your purpose:

```
var values = $(".agency_field").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
alert(values.join(","));
```

Comment: @karim79: Never seen this before... Interesting approach. How does this compare speed wise to each/push? Time for some api reading methinks..

Comment: @karim No need for `.join(",")`. When arrays coerce to strings, the commas are added by default.

Comment: @James South - I can't imagine there would be any perceptible difference in performance for a typical application. I use it because it was literally designed for sucking properties out of collections in a concise manner, as the manual says: *"The .map() method is particularly useful for getting or setting the value of a collection of elements."*

Comment: @Šime Vidas - I know, I put it there to highlight that what we're getting is an array.

Comment: @karim: Qood to know. Cheers!

Comment: @James According to [this little test](http://jsperf.com/map-vs-each-2), the map() solution is 40% slower. However, for a collection of 10 input fields, the times are 0,01ms for each() and 0,017ms for map(), which is a difference of 7 microseconds (on my machine).

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Thanks for that. For small numbers that certainly doesn't make much of a difference. If I was going to trail through something in the thousands I'd probably skip jQuery and go for a descending while.....Interesting to note though as I am a fan of the syntax.

Comment: @James My recommendation would be to not even think about descending whiles or what not, until you **notice** performance issues in practice. So, take an old laptop, open your page in IE, and test the performance. If a certain task takes longer than say 100ms, consider optimizations. Otherwise, don't bother. Premature optimization is a waste of time.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: For most situation i'd certainly go the more readable route and stick with the jquery but sometimes at my work i have to really tweak some stuff to get the best possible performance. That's why I was interested in the speed. Cheers though.

Comment: @Šime Vidas - awesome comments! I had not read them before now. How does one use this 'jsPerf.com' website?

Comment: @karim Just open the homepage - http://jsperf.com - and fill out the form fields. It's easy to use, you should get the hang of it in no time. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var agencies = [];
$(".agency_field").each(function(index) { agencies.push($(this).val()); });
```

Comment: @stef, you shouldn't choose the first answer. You should choose the best answer - which in this case is karim's by vote count.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new array for each iteration.  Try instead instantiating an array before the each call and adding to the array each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = []; $(".agency_field").each(function(index) { arr.push($(this).val()); });
```

`arr` would contain what you want in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your code shd be slightly changed to:

```
var agencies = [];
$(".agency_field").each(function(index) { 
    agencies.push($(this).val()); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array initially and then add each value to that array:

```
var agencies = [];
$(".agency_field").each(function(index) { agencies.push($(this).val()) });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're quite used to a language like php? ;)
In Javascript, you'd use array.push() for appending to an array; so

```
$(".agency_field").each(function(index) { agencies.push( $(this).val() ); });
```